How I can match each returned embedding with the text I gave to him so I can save them into a db?
I made this script that reads the text frpom pdf and for each paragraph calculates the mebddings using cohere embeddings api:

import os
import cohere
import time

from pypdf import PdfReader
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from qdrant_client import QdrantClient
from qdrant_client.models import Distance, VectorParams

load_dotenv()

docsFolder='./docs'

def getTextFromPDF(fileName):
    text = ""
    reader = PdfReader(fileName)
    for page in reader.pages:
        text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
    return text

def getPhrases(docsFolder):
    phrases=[]

    with os.scandir(docsFolder) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
                text=getTextFromPDF(docsFolder+"/"+entry.name)
                passages = [p.strip() for p in text.split("\n\n") if p.strip()]
                phrases.extend(passages)

    return phrases

start = time.perf_counter()
phrases = getPhrases(docsFolder)
end = time.perf_counter()

print("Passage Extraction time "+str(end-start)+" seconds")

co = cohere.ClientV2(api_key=os.getenv("COHERE_KEY"))

start = time.perf_counter()
res = co.embed(texts=phrases,model="embed-multilingual-v3.0", input_type="search_document",embedding_types=['float'])
end = time.perf_counter()

print("Embeddings generation time: "+str(end-start)+" seconds")

print(len(res.texts),len(res.embeddings.float),len(phrases))

# Save results here

What I want do do is to map the input texts with it embedding returned from cohere api so I can save them. The reason why is to use them at a later point and not to re-calculate them.
But what I find it hard it whether each item of res.embeddings.float is in order that phrases were given as input.

Each item of is a list that represents a vector. In your code the res.embeddings.float[0] represents the embedding of phrases[0] also res.embeddings.float[1] represent the mbedding of phrases[1].
In order to demonstrate that my answer is true I siplified a bit your piece of code:
import os
import cohere
import time

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from hashlib import sha256

load_dotenv()

docsFolder='./docs'

co = cohere.ClientV2(api_key=os.getenv("COHERE_KEY"))

phraseList=[
    ["lala","lala"],
    ["lala","leo"],
    ["leo","lala"],
    ["lala","leo","lala"]
]

for phrases in phraseList:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    res = co.embed(texts=phrases,model="embed-multilingual-v3.0", input_type="search_document",embedding_types=['float'])
    end = time.perf_counter()

    print("Embeddings generation time: "+str(end-start)+" seconds")

    with open('debug.txt',"a") as fp:
        fp.write("#######\n")
        
        for i,phrase in enumerate(phrases):
            fp.write(str(i)+" "+phrase+"\n")
        
        fp.write("Vector Hashes\n")
        
        for i,embeding in enumerate(res.embeddings.float):
            embedingStr=str(embeding)
            vectorHash=sha256(embedingStr.encode())
            fp.write(str(i)+" "+vectorHash.hexdigest()+"\n")
        
        fp.close()


What I did is that I placed fixed values upon input given in cohere api. The inputs I provided are stratigicaly chosen, behind my choice that if I provide same text cohere will calculate same value for each one, then by making a hash I make it easier for the eye to compare the values.
A result of mine was:
#######
0 lala
1 lala
Vector Hashes
0 ffe7f10c7b089ceeb0593e52b1d0be8e4307e52a4ac027a892fc816b973b3665
1 ffe7f10c7b089ceeb0593e52b1d0be8e4307e52a4ac027a892fc816b973b3665
#######
0 lala
1 leo
Vector Hashes
0 ffe7f10c7b089ceeb0593e52b1d0be8e4307e52a4ac027a892fc816b973b3665
1 4d74469f6f1b767dcf0228312878c7ee0ec495c38a3d52368d11fdc5e460bf19
#######
0 leo
1 lala
Vector Hashes
0 4d74469f6f1b767dcf0228312878c7ee0ec495c38a3d52368d11fdc5e460bf19
1 ffe7f10c7b089ceeb0593e52b1d0be8e4307e52a4ac027a892fc816b973b3665
#######
0 lala
1 leo
2 lala
Vector Hashes
0 e4ba92d371000933d8008e6cc53c1955897fd278d5c7c17eff6bce5ce146f47b
1 af41b7f0bc3a1410e32b0c3bb75d584b7e05141d27d6c6e31b95af7f13542b3c
2 e4ba92d371000933d8008e6cc53c1955897fd278d5c7c17eff6bce5ce146f47b


As you can see when value is lala the hash is the same but once I change the string hash differs. Thus by recording the array position with the hash I could assume that res.embeddings.float[0] will represent the embedding of phrases[0]
